# How to enable logging of python script in yocto poky layer?

Tags: python, logging, yocto, bitbake, yocto-wic

I want to see all the logs which are thrown by a python script present in yocto poky layer for my debugging.

> How do I do that?

Python script location - `poky/scripts/lib/wic/plugins/source/bootimg-pcbios.py`

Comment: you can always enable debugging when you use bitbake . bitbake <target> -v -D

Comment: It doesn't give any logs from `bootimg-pcbios.py`, even tried -DDD options also.

Comment: Which Yocto version do you use? Maybe try to call wic directly without bitbake?

Comment: I am using warrior. Is there such command for wic to use it directly?